# Relation concept between tables of SQL Server

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have a `Picture` table that generate by this model via entity framework :

```
public class Picture
{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a model that should have two picture columns : `aboutpicture` and `headerpicture`, what's the best way to declare them in this model class ??? What have done is look like this

```
 public class WebContent
 {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string AboutText { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreationTime { get; set; }
        public Picture AboutPicture { get; set; }
        public Picture HeaderPicture { get; set; }

 }
```

but I'm in doubt about relation of them

summary of my question , WebContent table should have two picture field

please help me about that , thanks